# Why "1.0" is not equal to "+1.0" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am doing a simple comparison in JavaScript but its not working.
Here is the script

```
var value = '1.0';
var minLimit = '+0.5';
var maxLimit = '+999';
if (value >= minLimit && value <= maxLimit) {
    console.log(value);
}
else
{
 console.log('not matched');
}
```

Is there anything I am missing comparison ? 
Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9ouwkyyt/

Comment: because you are doing a string comparison  - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9ouwkyyt/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is because you are doing a string comparison, not a numeric value comparison.

Convert the values to numeric values - you can use a unary plus, Number() or parseFloat() based on your need

```js
var value = +'1.0';
var minLimit = +'+0.5';
var maxLimit = +'+999';
if (value >= minLimit && value <= maxLimit) {
  console.log(value);
} else {
  console.log('not matched');
}
```

Comment: got it so I need to parse all values to float before comparison.. Thanks dear :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is a diffirence between '+999' and +999.

The one with quotes is a string, whereas the one without is a integer value. What you want to do is numeric comparison, not string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You only compare string, since if you want compare in integer format convert result into integer.

```
var value = '1.0';
    var minLimit = '+0.5';
    var maxLimit = '+999';
    if (parseInt(value )>= parseInt(minLimit) && parseInt(value )<= parseInt(maxLimit)) {
        console.log(value);
    }
    else
    {
     console.log('not matched');
    }
```

Comment: Add some explanation. Right now you hit the low quality queue because this is code only